# Does a thin tandem 2x15amp breaker draw 15 or 30 amps for a panel load calculation?

Tags: electrical-panel

I've multiple thin tandem breakers in my new home, and I suspect the panel is overloaded.

Does a 2x15 amp thin tandem breaker add 30amps or 15amps for a panel load calculation? I suspect 30, but I want to make sure.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the panel? Why  do you suspect the panel is overloaded?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe the panel is overloaded, such as frequently-tripped breakers? A load calculation is based on the *loads* served, not the receptacles available

Comment: From https://www.artplumbingandac.com/electrical/how-to-solve-an-overloaded-electrical-box-issue/ "Simply put, your electrical box is overloaded when your home’s power usage exceeds what your panel can handle." Has your home energy usage exceeded the capabilities of your incoming service? My home has a 100 amp service and I probably have 200-300 amps worth of breakers because I'm trying to run the appropriate amount of circuits instead of having half the house powered on one circuit like the bad ol' days.

Answer (score 9):

No.  The breakers **have no effect whatsoever on the panel load calculation**.

Because load calculations *do not work that way*.

Load calculations are based on house square footage and major electrical appliances.  Adding a Tesla EVSE has an effect.  Adding an addition has an effect.  Fewer vs more receptacle/lighting branch circuits has no effect.

Think about it. Suppose you buy a house and you find all the bedrooms and living room and outdoor outlets sharing 1 circuit.  However, the builder actually ran 7 homeruns for all these; they just landed them all on the same breaker.   It's an effortless job to split them all out, so you just get 6 more breakers. Now each has a breaker.  **Did you change the load calculation on the house or panel?  Does the house now have more square footage? Did you add any major appliances?  No, not at all**. It's the same house with the same loads.  There are just more breakers behind the loads.

Or, you build a house to NEC minimums with 1 recep circuit for all 3 bathrooms.  I build the same house, but because Harper, I wire 2 dedicated 20A circuits per bathroom.  Yours all fits in a 24-space panel, I installed dual 40s.  Our square footage and major appliances are identical.  Are our load calculations different? NO.

---

The only thing that double-stuff breaker is relevant to is stab limits.  That's 30A worth of stab load, so across from it can't be more than a 95A breaker if it's the usual 125A stab limit.

Comment: Only quibble: those 2 extra SABCs in the kitchen do add 3kVA of factorable load to the calculation, since kitchen/laundry SABCs are counted there.  The bathrooms by themselves are a good example, though

Answer (score 1):

A 2x15 allows the addition of TWO 15A circuits.  So the total possible is 30A, 15A out of each side.

But breakers are not run at 100%, so your total of all the breakers may exceed the main breaker rating.